# How to use get_FOO_display() to access an uninstantiated model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

Am new to programming and I would like to access the `get_FOO_display()` function for the below model before having any objects (database entries). I know I can use `SubOrder.EXTRA_CHOICES` and `SubOrder._meta.get_field()`, but in both cases I get a list of tuples returned `(M, 'Mushrooms'), (P, 'Peppers'), etc`.

How can I just get `Mushrooms, Peppers, etc.` as a list?

I tried `SubOrder._meta.get_extra_display()` but I get an `AttributeError`: `'Options' object has no attribute 'get_extra_display'` - Django's Model _meta API doesn't seem to allow that. My model is below:

```
class SubOrder(Sub):
  item_id = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name="sub_item_id")
  extra_count = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(4), MinValueValidator(0)])
  MUSHIES = 'M'
  PEPPERS = 'P'
  ONIONS = 'O'
  XTRCHEESE = 'C'
  EXTRA_CHOICES = ((MUSHIES, 'Mushrooms'), (PEPPERS, 'Peppers'), (ONIONS, 'Onions'), (XTRCHEESE, 'Extra Cheese'),)
  extra = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=EXTRA_CHOICES, blank=True)
```

Comment: The `get_FOO_display()` returns the value for a particular instance, so it doesn't make sense to access it without an instance. To get the list of descriptions, you could do `[y for x,y in SubOrder.EXTRA_CHOICES]`.

Comment: Yes I just did that now - was just curious about whether or how that would work using _meta or model rather than specific object info... thanks :)

Comment: Django doesn't add the `get_FOO_display` methods to the meta class, so `SubOrder._meta.get_extra_display()` doesn't make sense. You can access `SubOrder.get_extra_display` on the class, but to call it you need an instance, e.g. `SubOrder.get_extra_display(SubOrder(extra=MUSHIES))`, and since you've instantiated an instance there, you might as well do `SubOrder(extra=MUSHIES).get_extra_display()`. In any case, `get_extra_display` only returns the display value for a single item, not all possible display values, so it's not really helpful to you.

Comment: @Alasdair thanks for this - you've answered/resolved all I was asking for - not sure how to convert your comment to an answer on here..